Accessing OAuth 2.0 Token Set in Next.js with NextAuth.js
I'm working on a Next.js project that uses a custom API service with OAuth 2.0 authentication. The authentication is managed with NextAuth.js (v5). I've implemented credential-based authentication and it works, but I'm having issues accessing the OAuth 2.0 token set on individual pages and updating it upon token refresh.
Here's my current setup:
auth.ts Configuration
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Credentials from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { apiClient } from '@services/apiClient'
import { config as appConfig } from '@config'

export const ServiceAuthProvider = Credentials({
    name: 'Credentials',
    credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' }
    },
    authorize: async (credentials) => {
        try {
            const tokenSet = await apiClient.signIn(credentials.username, credentials.password);
            const userProfile = await apiClient.meProfileGet({
                query: { includeProfileImage: 'true' },
                userAccessToken: tokenSet.access_token
            }).then(result => result.data);

            const image = userProfile.profileImage?.filename 
                ? `${appConfig.service.apiBaseUrl}${userProfile.profileImage.filename}`
                : `https://robohash.org/${userProfile.userId}?set=set2&bgset=bg2&size=150x150`;

            return {
                name: `${userProfile.firstName} ${userProfile.lastName}`,
                email: userProfile.email,
                image: image,
                tokenSet: tokenSet,
            };
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Error during sign-in', e);
            throw new Error('User not found.');
        }
    }
});

const providers = [ServiceAuthProvider];

export default NextAuth({
    providers,
    pages: { signIn: '/sign-in' },
    callbacks: {
        jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
            if (user) {
                token.accessToken = user.tokenSet.access_token;
                token.tokenSet = user.tokenSet;
            }
            return token;
        },
        session: ({ session, token }) => {
            session.tokenSet = token.tokenSet;
            return session;
        },
    },
    debug: true,
});

Issue 1: Accessing Token Set on Individual Pages
In my page component, I'm trying to access the user's session and token set using auth() from NextAuth.js. However, the token set is not included in the session data:
import { auth } from '@/auth'

export default async function Profile() {
  const session = await auth();
  const user = session?.user;

  return (
    <>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(user)}</pre>
    </>
  );
}

This results in:
{"name":"Ace Dace","email":"ace.dace@platform.dev","image":"https://localhost/media/hVvKe3d9vE4lC2e6/users/FJOn8xAor1epID3f/profile_QzoaY7vMaVpS6D.jpg"}

Questions

How can I ensure the token set is included in the session data when accessing individual pages?

How can I update the token set and store it in the user's session upon refreshing the OAuth 2.0 token by using API client?


Additional Information
The callbacks in auth.ts are working as expected, and I can see the token set in the console logs. However, when I call auth() in a page, the tokenSet is missing from the session.
Here’s an example of the console output:
Callback JWT {
  name: 'Ace Dace',
  email: 'ace.dace@platform.dev',
  picture: 'https://localhost/media/hVvKe3d9vE4lC2e6/users/FJOn8xAor1epID3f/profile_QzoaY7vMaVpS6D.jpg',
  sub: '25dddc8a-ed60-4b43-aaa8-74b3f0f98366',
  accessToken: '****.****.****',
  tokenSet: {
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    access_token: '****.****.****',
    refresh_token: '****.****.****',
    expires_in: 1440,
    expires_at: '2024-06-09T21:07:11.891Z'
  },
  iat: 1717969628,
  exp: 1720561628,
  jti: '06b9c2dc-0f8f-43d5-b393-06e4049e6d09'
} undefined

Callback session {
  user: {
    name: 'Ace Dace',
    email: 'ace.dace@platform.dev',
    image: 'https://localhost/media/hVvKe3d9vE4lC2e6/users/FJOn8xAor1epID3f/profile_QzoaY7vMaVpS6D.jpg'
  },
  expires: '2024-07-09T21:47:19.195Z'
} {
  name: 'Ace Dace',
  email: 'ace.dace@platform.dev',
  picture: 'https://localhost/media/hVvKe3d9vE4lC2e6/users/FJOn8xAor1epID3f/profile_QzoaY7vMaVpS6D.jpg',
  sub: '25dddc8a-ed60-4b43-aaa8-74b3f0f98366',
  accessToken: '****.****.****',
  tokenSet: {
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    access_token: '****.****.****',
    refresh_token: '****.****.****',
    expires_in: 1440,
    expires_at: '2024-06-09T21:07:11.891Z'
  },
  iat: 1717969628,
  exp: 1720561628,
  jti: '06b9c2dc-0f8f-43d5-b393-06e4049e6d09'
}

